# Need to write test functions from scratch in python

Tags: python, unit-testing, if-statement, calculator, python-module

I have just started learning python and I need to write some test functions for an assignment. I can't use any testing framework or "assert" bcz that hasn't been taught in the class yet. Also, all my functions are in a module that is going to be imported in the main file. I also want to write the test functions in the main file.

But there wasn't much in class about how to write testing functions and I didn't find any good examples of test functions that I can refer to.

I wanted to try to write it myself, but the one I wrote just doesn't give the expected result.
So I just hope to look at some relevant examples that might give me some framework to work on. Maybe a sample test function to test a simple python calculator or a test function for sum and product of n numbers. Thank you.

Here is part of the code for one of the functions in the module,

```
def sum_ave(a,b):
    return sum_value(a,b)
    return avg(a,b)

def sum_1(a,b):
    return (a+b) 
    return c # c= float(a)+float(b)
    
def averg(a,b):
    return ((a+b)/2)
    return avg     # avg=float(c/2)
    

while True:
....
```

Here is the code for testing I tried to use,

```
def test_1():
    """Test 1"""
    print(test_1.__doc__)
    
    if sum_1([2],[4])==[6] and averg([2],[4])==[3]:
        print("Test_1: pass\n")
    else:
        print("Test_1: fail\n")
```

This code always results in "Test_1: fail". Actually I started this code with sum([2,4])==[6], but this gives me error, "sum() missing 1 required positional argument: 'b' ".

Comment: It doesn't make sense to have a `return` followed by another `return`.

Comment: Also, keep in mind that `[2] + [4] == [2, 4]`, not `[6]`.

Comment: Thanks for providing context, code attempts, and current output. Your post is only missing a couple more things to being a "good question". Because this is a "help me debug" question, what output are you expecting instead, and why are you expecting that? Providing your current best understanding is important when asking a "help me understand" question.

Comment: @Kache I wanted to create a test function which will call and execute the functions in the module with set input (provided in the test functions), compare it with the set output and display if it passed or failed. I think one of my problem was that I was using an if statement and was expecting it to execute function sum_1(a,b). :( Thank you for your comment.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think what you are looking for is something like the following. A function that takes as arguments the function you are going to test and the expected value. In this example, `sum_1` is the function we want to test. We pass it as an argument to the `test_function` along with the expected value. The test function compares the result of function with the `expected_val` and prints a success or failure message accordingly.

```py
# The function you defined
def sum_1(a, b):
    return a + b
    
# Generic test function 
def test_function(function, expected_val):
    if function == expected_val:
        print("✅Test passed")
    else:
        print("❌Test failed")

# Test sum_1
test_function(sum_1(2,4), 6)

# Failed test example
test_function(sum_1(2,4), 7)
```

The function is generic, meaning that it works for functions that always return a value.